# RegEx pattern in facelet doesnt work

Tags: regex, jsf

i have a problem with the RegEx expression.
It doesnt work, that means it doesnt matter what i enter in the inputText.
Only when i enter nothing, i get the "Thats wrong" message. If i use a function or class in the BackingBean everything works fine.

Maybe someone can help me.
Thank you. Matze

```html
<h:form>
     <h:inputText id="Name" value="#{Data.name}" validatorMessage="Thats wrong" > 
          <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{2,30}$" for="Name"  > 
          <f:validateRequired for="Name"></f:validateRequired> </f:validateRegex>  
     </h:inputText>
     <h:message for="Name"/>
     <h:commandButton id="Button" action="index.xhtml"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What language is that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should omit `^` and `$` ... Try to use

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Z][a-zA-Z]{2,30}" for="Name" />
```